# Metod from the mocked bean is not working correctly

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I want to create unit test for a method in service meaning I don't want to use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` although it would have solved my problem.

This is what my program looks like:

```java
    @Service
    public class MyService {
      private final SomeBean someBean;
      public MyService(SomeBean someBean) {
        this.someBean = someBean;
      }
      public boolean functionToTest() {
        boolean b = someBean.innerFunction();  // inside innerFunction() I return always true;
        return b;
        }
      }
    }

    public class SomeBean extends BaseBean {
      private String value;  // getter, setter
      public SomeBean(String value) {      //this value is always null in test
        super();
        this.value = value;
      }
      public boolean innerFunction() {
        return true;
      }
    }

    @Configuration
    public class SomeBeanConfiguration {
      @Bean
      public SomeBean getSomeBean(@Value("${prop.value}") String value) {
        return new SomeBean(value);  //can't get here while debugging test
      }
    }
```

And this is how I want to test `functionToTest()`:

```java
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class MyTest {

      @InjectMocks
      MyService service;

      @Mock
      SomeBean someBean;

      @Before
      public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);    //although result is the same even without this set up
      }

      @Test
      public void test() {
        assertTrue(service.functionToTest());
      }
    }
```

The test always fails because `boolean b` is `false` by default and I can't get into innerFunction() with debugger.

Is there any way to mock beans for this kind of unit testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `MockitoJUnitRunner` that is why your Spring configuration is not launched during tests - context is not being created. But that is not the main problem here as you want to unit test your logic.

If you wanted to unit test your spring beans, which would be taken from Spring Context, you would probably be using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` (for JUnit4) and `@MockBean` (only available in Spring Boot) annotations for mocking beans in the Spring Context for tests.

When you create a mock - with mockito - you have to actually say what this mock should do when method is called on it. For example :

```
Mockito.when(someBean.innerFunction()).thenReturn(true);
```

Here you say "when method `innerFunction` is invoked on my mock object, please return true".

So your test could look like :

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Mockito.when(someBean.innerFunction()).thenReturn(true);
    assertTrue(service.functionToTest());
}
```

Additionally you do not need to use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in `@Before` annotated method because you are already using `@InjectMocks` annotation.

Comment: `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` was not necessary in this case, the only thing I added was `Mockito.when(someBean.innerFunction()).thenReturn(true);` and it worked. Now I see that to test real `innerFunction()` I need to test it separately

Comment: `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` is only needed when you need spring context for your tests. Here you are using `MockitoJUnitRunner.class` and that is fine as long as you want to use Mockito to create mocks and you do not need Spring to create you beans.

Comment: And here by mocking `someBean` you actually unit test your service - that is why you mock `someBean` which is a dependency for your service. Also consider accepting the answer if it was helpful :)